# How to iterate with getting value over a large list of int's (10+millions)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am rewriting the library from C#, which scans memory for patterns. I need to scan the process memory from the starting address to the end, it takes about 13+ million bytes in the list. Next, I need to find a pattern in this list through the condition, where 'offset' is the byte value from the iterator.

In C#, I just used for-loop for 1 pattern and scanning took about 800ms, but in python, I didn’t fully learn this language, but I tried for-range, which took about 35! seconds, the only thing I found is numpy.where, but I can't apply it to my condition.

What i tried:

```
loop_len = range(len(self.exe_image) - pattern_length)
for offset in filter(lambda o: self.__compare_data(pattern, o), loop_len):
```

What i need to do with the offset:

```
def __compare_data(self, pattern: Pattern, offset: int):
      return not any(filter(lambda i: pattern.mask[i] == 'x' and pattern.bytes[i] != self.exe_image[offset + i],
                              range(len(pattern.bytes))))
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Probably the fastest way to search for a pattern in Python would be to use a regular expression via the included [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) module.

Comment: @martineau unfortunately, this method doesn't work for my situation, may be, the easiest way it's write a dll specifically for for-loop? because even in normal situations a C-loop takes about 14 ms, while a python is about 300 and higher.

Comment: @JacobIRR 3.7.3

Comment: Shader: You could certainly could write a C extension to do it. However, I don't see why use a regular expression would not work — so what about your situation prevented it?

Answer (score 0):

Python is much slower than a compiled language like C#. One solution is using a python compiler like [`Cython`](https://cython.org/) or a JIT compiler like [`Numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/). With these you can use your existing python code with few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is interested, then instead of JIT i used regex + bytearray.index.
i converted the exe-bytearray to a string of int values and found the pattern via regex.search, then converted it to bytearray and found the index via bytearray.index

my example:

```py
search_for = str(pattern.bytes)[1:-1].replace('-1', '.{1,3}')  # -1 it's unknown byte
match = re.search(search_for, exe_image_as_str)
```

then:

```py
offset = exe_image.index(bytearray(int(i) for i in match.group(0).split(', ')))
```